# Is this mechanism of reduction using LiAlH4 followed by hydrolysis of an amide correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

[image]

Hello everyone. I had been given a question on reducing an amide group into an amine group using any reagent I saw fit as homework. I had used LiAlH4, which provides H- and does an acid base reaction with nh-h+, and then uses its pi electrons to kick out carbonyl pi bond back to the oxygen, followed by addition of more H- to form R-ch2-nh followed by hydrolysis which gives r-ch2-nh2. so how correct is this?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50534/why-does-lialh4-reduce-an-amide-to-an-amine-but-only-reduce-a-ketone-aldehyde-t

Comment: How correct? Well, moderately ;) It's very sketchy, but goes in right direction.